# Trying to simplify Root expressions from the output of Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix

I am trying to calculate eigenvalues of a sparse matrix with only two distinct non-zero elements, here Alpha and Beta, which are both negative reals.  Mathematica returns some complex expressions with `Root[]` values when using the `Eigenvalues[]` command on the following matrixA:

In all cases the matrices are symmetric and real and hence have real eigenvalues.

```
matrixA={
        {α, β, 0, 0, 0, 0, β, 0, 0, β},
        {β, α, β, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, β, α, β, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, β, α, β, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, β, α, β, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, β, α, β, 0, 0, 0},
        {β, 0, 0, 0, 0, β, α, β, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, β, α, β, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, β, α, β},
        {β, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, β, α}
        }
```

For comparison, with all the other similar matrices I've tried (see below e.g. matrixB) Mathematica will put out simple decimal approximations (using `Eigenvalues[matrixB] // N // Simplify`)

Can anyone point out a way to get expressions for the `matrixA` as simple as for `matrixB`?

And yes, the desired simple answers for `matrixA` do exist, I can get them with other programs, but I want to use Mathematica!

---

I should add that I already have already used `$Assumptions = α<0 && β <0` at the top of my worksheet.

```
matrixB={
        {α, β, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, β},
        {β, α, β, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, β, α, β, 0, 0, 0, β, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, β, α, β, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, β, α, β, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, β, α, β, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, β, α, β, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, β, 0, 0, 0, β, α, β, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, β, α, β},
        {β, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, β, α}
        }
```

Comment: You don't need the `//N` for `matrixB`: there is an analytical solution. If the highest power of the eigenvalues for matrixA is higher than those for matrixB, they won't be "as simple".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I figured out how the other programs do get numeric answers.  Of course the trick is to eliminate the symbols.  Since `matrixA` is so simply structured it can be massaged into a non-symbolic form, calculate numerically the eigenvalues of that, and then unmassage them to recover the symbolic eigenvalues.  Divide the whole matrix by `β` then "re-zero" the main diagonal to `α/β`.

For reference,

```
reducedmatrixA=({
      {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
      {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
     } )

numericeigenvalues = Sort[Eigenvalues[reducedmatrixA] // Simplify // N]
symboliceigenvalues = α + β numericeigenvalues
```

does the trick.  Thanks everyone for your pointers on the algebra.

Comment: If all you want is the approximate numerical values, it is a lot quicker to calculate `Sort[Eigenvalues[reducedmatrixA // N]]` than `Sort[Eigenvalues[reducedmatrixA] // Simplify // N]`

Answer (score 12):

The reason why you can't get a simple expression for eigenvalues is that the characterisitc polynomial of `matrixA` is not factorizable (in general) to lower order polynomials, unlike for `matrixB`.

```
CharacteristicPolynomial[matrixA, x] // Factor
```

[image]

```
CharacteristicPolynomial[matrixB, x] // Factor
```

[image]

There is no general method of solving sixth order polynomial equations, unlike for forth order ones. 
In general, you can still simplify a bit the expression for eigenvalues of `matrixA` adding an option `Quartics -> True` to `Eigenvalues` :

```
Eigenvalues[matrixA, Quartics -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the thorough explanation I should have known of.  I'm still looking for numerical approximations, though.  I have other software that gives the results, but I don't know how to replicate that in Mathematica.

Comment: @WilliamKennerly Can you post the result that the other software gives you?

Comment: @R.M Here you go.  The answers are in the form (\Alpha - C\Beta), with the 10 values of C:
-2.310  -1.652  -1.356  -0.887  -0.477   0.400   0.738   1.579   1.869   2.095

I'm sure that program is just doing a straight numerical diagonalization, say with LAPACK... so is there some way to get Mathematica to do that?

Comment: I doubt this is really correct in general,  it would be if the associated Galois group of the characteristic polynomial is solvable, which is not the case here. I suppose there is an implicit assumption of solvability of the group, this could be true only for special values of alpha and beta. Look for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html

Answer (score 5):

Presumably those other systems are making some assumptions about the values of `α` and `β`, which Mathematica does not. Mathematica's symbolic engine does not assume that symbols represent real-valued quantities.

You can probably get some simplification using the `Assuming` construct or the `Assumptions` option to `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`, like this:

```
FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[matrixA], 
 Assumptions -> {Element[α, Reals], Element[β, Reals]}]
```

Or even:

```
FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[matrixA], 
 Assumptions -> {α > 0, β > 0}]
```

The latter simplifies the first eigenvalue to:

> `α - 1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[2 (11 + Sqrt[5])]) β`

However, some of the others are still higher-order expressions represented by `Root` expressions.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of `FullSimplify[]`...  that gets 4 out of 10 of numerical approximations to the eigenvalues.  So not all the way there yet. However I should have originally said that I do run the command `$Assumptions=\[Alpha]<0 && \[Beta] <0` before I do any of the eigenvalue calculations.